# Count # of Similar Records, Average Count and # with specific count

Tags: mysql, count

I have a MySql table with a non-Unique Name Field, I'd like to query the following;

For each Name Value ("John") count how many records there are (32 records with name John), I'll end up writing this to each record.

Average the counts for each name group (e.g 32 records with John and 42 records with Sally, Average for table 37 records)

Count counts meaning e.g 6 10 Record groups, 10 20-record groups, etc

Can I do this with one or more queries?

Comment: Non-unique but indexed field? right?

Answer (score 1):

Average for Table Groups http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5af3/5:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(ct) 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(name) as ct 
  FROM 
    names 
  GROUP BY  
    name) as temp1;
```

Count per count http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0628/1:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(ct) AS "Count_per_count",
  ct as "Actual Count" 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(name) as ct 
  FROM 
    names 
  GROUP BY 
    name) as temp1 
GROUP BY ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, count(*) as num from table group by name;

select ((select count(*) from table) / (select count(distinct name) from table));

select count(*) as num, type from
    (select count(*) as type from table group by name) t
group by type
```